# having an effect dispatch different action in different case

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have the following effect

```
  @Effect()
  assignMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.AssignUAVMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.AssignUAVMissionRequest),
    concatMap(action =>
      of(action).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(RoutesStoreSelectors.getById(), {routeId: action.payload.routeId}))),
      )
    ),
    switchMap(([action, route]) => {
      return this.dataService.assignUAVMission(action.payload.params).pipe(
        mergeMap(response => {
          if (route.saveState === RoutesStoreModels.IRouteSaveState.DRAWED) {
            return [
              new RoutesStoreActions.OverrideRoute(),
              new featureActions.AssignUAVMissionSuccess()
            ];
          } else {
            const newRouteId = uuid();
            return [
              new RoutesStoreActions.AddRoute(),
              new featureActions.AssignUAVMissionSuccess()
            ];
          }
        }),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          return of(new featureActions.AssignUAVMissionFailed({error}));
        }),
      );
    })
  );
```

in one case, I want to dispatch `OverrideRoute` and `AssignUAVMissionSuccess`
in another case I want to dispatch `AddRoute` and `AssignUAVMissionSuccess` instead.

the problem is, my mergeMap return an error

> ERROR in src/app/stores/uavs-store/effects.ts(218,18): error TS2345:
>   Argument of type '(response: AssignMissionResponse) =>
>   (AssignUAVMissionSuccess | OverrideRoute)[] | (AssignUAVMissionSuccess
>   | AddRoute)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value:
>   AssignMissionResponse, index: number) =>
>   ObservableInput'.

But I don't exactly see how is this fixable ?

Is it possible to have an effect dispatch different set of action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by returning an array of type `Action` like this -

```
mergeMap(response => {

          const actions = new Array<Action>();
          if (route.saveState === RoutesStoreModels.IRouteSaveState.DRAWED) {
          actions.push(new RoutesStoreActions.OverrideRoute());
           actions.push(
              new featureActions.AssignUAVMissionSuccess()
            );
           return actions;
          } else {
            const newRouteId = uuid();
           actions.push(new RoutesStoreActions.AddRoute());
           actions.push(
              new featureActions.AssignUAVMissionSuccess()
            );
            return actions;
          }
        })
```

Comment: This works, I do not understand exactly the problem, is it because mergeMap is expecting the same time of Observable to merge ?

thank for the solution, is it the only solution you think?

Comment: @Bobby why it works and not the direct return [] works. This is because effect expects return type as Observable<Action> but direct return [] with different type of new actions does not make compiler happy so array.push works. It is little weird but this the best I could think of:) This is the only solutions I found. Even in my team we all use this approach and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Bobby when returning [], passes actions were not structurally same. That was the reason it was not working.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue, I use also direct [...] or from([...]) and it's working with my actions. I really would like to go deeper, reproduce and try to better understand. @Bobby Could you give more details on your `actions.ts` please ? Are you using namespaces ? Thanks.